# Sequential RTK Query Execution in React Component: Handling Data Dependencies

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm facing an issue with using RTK Query in React. I have two queries, **useGetProfileByUserIdQuery** and **useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery**. When my component is initially rendered, the **classId** required by **useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery** is **undefined** because both queries are executed simultaneously.

Below is a snippet of my component:

```
const currentUser = useSelector(selectCurrentUser);
const userId = currentUser.userId;

const { data: profileData } = useGetProfileByUserIdQuery(userId);
const classId = profileData?.data?.class?.id;

const { data: schedules, isLoading: getSchedulesLoading } =
useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery({ classId, day: selectedDay });
```

Full Code of my component:

```
import {
  Box,
  CircularProgress,
  Container,
  Paper,
  Tab,
  Tabs,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery } from "../schedulesApiSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectCurrentUser } from "../../auth/authSlice";
import { useGetProfileByUserIdQuery } from "../../profile/profileApiSlice";

const formatTime = (dateString) => {
  const options = { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };
  return new Date(dateString).toLocaleTimeString(undefined, options);
};

const StudentScheduleList = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState("Senin");

  const currentUser = useSelector(selectCurrentUser);
  const userId = currentUser.userId;

  const { data: profileData } = useGetProfileByUserIdQuery(userId);
  const classId = profileData?.data?.class?.id;

  const { data: schedules, isLoading: getSchedulesLoading } =
    useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery({ classId, day: selectedDay });

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);

    const selectedDayLabel = [
      "Senin",
      "Selasa",
      "Rabu",
      "Kamis",
      "Jumat",
      "Sabtu",
      "Minggu",
    ][newValue];
    setSelectedDay(selectedDayLabel);
  };

  return (
    <Container sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Daftar Jadwal
      </Typography>

      <Paper>
        <Box
          sx={{
            maxWidth: { xs: 320, sm: 480, md: 720, lg: 960, xl: 1280 },
            bgcolor: "background.paper",
            marginX: "auto",
          }}
        >
          <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons
            allowScrollButtonsMobile
            aria-label="scrollable"
          >
            <Tab label="Senin" />
            <Tab label="Selasa" />
            <Tab label="Rabu" />
            <Tab label="Kamis" />
            <Tab label="Jumat" />
            <Tab label="Sabtu" />
            <Tab label="Minggu" />
          </Tabs>

          {getSchedulesLoading ? (
            <Box
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                alignItems: "center",
                padding: "20px",
              }}
            >
              <CircularProgress />
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center">
                Loading...
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          ) : schedules?.length ? (
            <Box>
              {schedules.map((schedule) => (
                <div key={schedule.id}>
                  <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                    {schedule.day}: {formatTime(schedule.start_time)} -{" "}
                    {formatTime(schedule.end_time)}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    Guru: {schedule.teacher.full_name}, Kelas:{" "}
                    {schedule.class.name}, Mata Pelajaran:{" "}
                    {schedule.subject.name}
                  </Typography>
                  {/* Tambahkan komponen lain sesuai kebutuhan */}
                </div>
              ))}
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <Box
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                alignItems: "center",
                padding: "20px",
              }}
            >
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center" gutterBottom>
                Tidak ada data.
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default StudentScheduleList;
```

What's the recommended approach for sequentially executing queries or waiting until the first query is completed before triggering the second one using RTK Query?

I attempted to address the issue by utilizing the skip parameter in the useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery query to conditionally execute it based on the availability of classId. My expectation was that this would ensure the second query only runs after the first one successfully retrieves the classId. However, the implementation did not fully resolve the problem, and classId remained undefined during the initial render.

Comment: **Resolution Steps:**
1. Added the `skip: !classId` property to `useGetScheduleByClassIdAndDayQuery` to skip the fetch when `classId` is not available.
2. Introduced `refetchSchedules` to trigger a re-fetch when `classId` becomes available and the tab is changed.
3. Utilized `handleChange` to handle tab changes, update `selectedDay`, and call `refetchSchedules`.

``````